# Sumologic sum two aggregates in search query

Tags: sumologic

What I am trying to achieve is to display sum of two aggregated fields sum(DiscoverCountOld) as VisitsDiscoveredOld and sum(DiscoverCount) as VisitsDiscovered as a new column instead of those two fields

```
  _source="src" and _collector="collector"
    | parse regex "Finished cataloging (?<DiscoverCountOld>\d+) visits for state " nodrop
    | parse regex "Finished cataloging visits: Visit count: (?<DiscoverCount>\d+)" nodrop
    | parse regex "Finished submitting (?<SubmitCount>\d+) visits for state CO" nodrop
    | parse regex "Finished updating status for (?<UpdateCount>\d+) visits for state CO"
    | fields DiscoverCountOld,DiscoverCount,SubmitCount,UpdateCount
    | timeslice 1d
    | sum(DiscoverCountOld) as VisitsDiscoveredOld,sum(DiscoverCount) as VisitsDiscovered, sum(SubmitCount) as VisitsSubmitted, sum(UpdateCount) as VisitsUpdated group by _timeslice
    | fillmissing timeslice(1d) 
    | sort by _timeslice asc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer found:

```
_source="_source" and _collector="-collector"
| parse regex "Finished cataloging (?<DiscoverCountOld>\d+) visits for state " nodrop
| parse regex "Finished cataloging visits: Visit count: (?<DiscoverCount>\d+)" nodrop
| parse regex "Finished submitting (?<SubmitCount>\d+) visits for state CO" nodrop
| parse regex "Finished updating status for (?<UpdateCount>\d+) visits for state CO"
| timeslice 1d
| sum(DiscoverCountOld) as VisitsDiscoveredOld,sum(DiscoverCount) as VisitsDiscoveredNew, sum(SubmitCount) as VisitsSubmitted, sum(UpdateCount) as VisitsUpdated group by _timeslice
| VisitsDiscoveredOld+VisitsDiscoveredNew as VisitsDiscovered
| fields _timeslice,VisitsDiscovered,VisitsSubmitted,VisitsUpdated
| fillmissing timeslice(1d)   
| sort by _timeslice asc
```